# Digital Clock Brightness

Tags: time

My alarm clock has a typical 7-segment digital display showing hours and minutes.

[image: 4:13]

Every lit segment is equally bright, and every unlit segment is equally dark. The separator (:) is always lit.

[image: 12:05]

Assuming the clock uses 12-hour time without a leading zero for the hours, at what time does the overall brightness (i.e., the total number of lit segments) of the display change the most?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Logic behind the answer:

> The biggest change in brightness is: 7->8 (+4), 0->1 (-4), 1->2 (+3), 6->7 (-3).
> Changing time by "tens," the greatest increase is from :19->:20 (+4), which is better than any single digit change.
> An hour change (:59->:00) results in +1 brightness, so it is "inefficient" to go down in brightness (change in a single digit, 6->7, is less than :19->:20, and going from 6:59->7:00, is only a change of (-1)).  So we are looking for an increase in brightness.

So, without really looking at anything else, my initial guess is:

> 7:59->8:00

resulting in:

> +5 brightness

Note:

> There is no `lateral thinking` tag, but when the clock is at 8:08, unplugging it results in a change of (-20) which is a greater change than (+6).

Edit:

> Nine is 6 digits, not 5 like I originally thought.

Comment: That "initial guess" looks good, but the math is off...ROT13(qbhoyr-purpx gur erfhyg bs mreb gb bar naq svsgl-avar gb mreb)

Comment: @zennehoy ROT13(vf avar 5 be 6 havgf)?

Comment: ROT13(avar vf fvk frtzragf)

Comment: @zennehoy ahh.  I corrected

Comment: Some googling later I found there actually are clocks with 5-segment nines... Can't remember ever having seen one in real though. Thanks for updating your answer!

Comment: To be honest, I didn't look it up and just assumed that it was 5 not 6.  But you are right, most are 6 :-)

Comment: @zennehoy: There are two common styles for each of 6, 7, and 9.  Displays which are used to show hex need the crossbar on the 6 to distinguish it from "b".  Digital clocks and watches often wire the top and bottom of the ten-minute segment together (the top, middle, and bottom segments all switch together for all digits except 4, 7, and possibly 6 and 9).  While that wouldn't affect how 6 and 9 are displayed, I think the electronics worked out most simply to make 4 and 7 be the only two exceptions to treating all three segments as a unit.  Incidentally, if one doesn't mind having...

Comment: ...a slightly weird 0 and a weirder 4, one could construct a display with different arrangement of 7 segments such that every digit would differ from every other by at least two segments.  Three segments would be the top, right, and bottom of a box, and the other four would be radii from the center to the corners.  In the common design, a six-segment 6 or 9 is only one segment different from 8, a three-segment 7 is only one segment different from 1, a normal four-segment 7 would be only one segment different from a five-segment 9, and an alternative four-segment 7 only one different from a 2.

Answer (score 7):

The answer has already been given, but I show my approach how to get there, just a simple bash script brute-forcing all possibilities:

```
#!/bin/bash
brightness(){
    local b=0 c
    for ((c=0;c<${#1};c++)); do
    case ${1:$c:1} in
        0) (( b+=6 )); ;;
        1) (( b+=2 )); ;;
        2) (( b+=5 )); ;;
        3) (( b+=5 )); ;;
        4) (( b+=4 )); ;;
        5) (( b+=5 )); ;;
        6) (( b+=6 )); ;;
        7) (( b+=3 )); ;;
        8) (( b+=7 )); ;;
        9) (( b+=6 )); ;;
    esac
done
echo $b
}
biggest_diff=0
bbefore=$(brightness 1159)
for h in {0..11}; do
for m in {00..59}; do
    bnow=$(brightness $h$m)
        diff=$(( bnow - bbefore ))
    if [ ${diff#-} -ge $biggest_diff ]; then
        biggest_diff=${diff#-}
            echo Diff: $diff
        echo Time: $h:$m
    fi
    bbefore=$bnow
    done;
done
```

Calling it returns ...

```
./clock | tail -n2
```

> Diff: 5
>  Time: 8:00

Comment: +1 Nice one. Well, your script is short enough to not have side effects. Nevertheless, it would be nicer to declare function-wide variables local. Just write `local c b=0` to declare `c` before the loop, and declare and assign `c`.

Comment: true, edited ...

Answer (score 4):

Well, it is

> +5 brightness from:
>
>  7:59 to 8:00

Since:

> total of `7:59` is 3 + 5 + 6 = 14
>  total of `8:00` is 7 + 6 + 6 = 19

Comment: Correct! Here's an upvote, but I'll accept Greg's answer since he has more reasoning.

Comment: Sure, no issue, he deserves it. I came to the answer using a computer :)